# Example GET request for the rendezvous doc

Tags: onion-services

Does anyone have an example of what GET request is needed to be send to the responsible HSDir server to retrieve the rendezvous2 document for a specified HS

currently I have

```
"GET HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:"+web_addresses+"\r\n\r\n"
```

but do not think this is correct as I am unable to retrieve the docs.

Answer (score 3):

You want to make a request of the form:

> GET /tor/rendezvous2/<descriptor-id> HTTP/1.0
>   Host: <HSDir-IP>:<HSDir-port>

A rather annoying thing about newer versions of Tor is that making a direct (unencrypted) HTTP request like that won't actually work. Instead you need to make the request over a circuit that ends at the HSDir.
I'm not completely sure of the details, but it's much easier using or modifying an existing Tor client (such as Orchid) than writing your own to do that.